# Not getting playlist name from Apple Music

Tags: ios, swift, mpmediaquery, apple-music, apple-musickit

I want to get Playlist Name, but it gives value of Mpconcreteitem.

```
let myQuery2 : MPMediaQuery = MPMediaQuery.playlists()
let playlist = myQuery2.collections
print(playlist!)


for album in playlist!{
    print("---------------")
    print("playlist \(String(describing: album.items)))")
    if album.items.count == 0 {

    } else {
          print(album.items[0].value(forProperty: "MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName") )
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that an MPMediaItem will have a reference to the playlists it is in.

I also think playlists only store songs (could be mistaken)

In any case to get a playlist name you want:

```
 let mediaQuery:MPMediaQuery = MPMediaQuery.playlists()

        for playlist in mediaQuery.collections! {
            print(playlist.value(forProperty: MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName) as Any)

        }
```